# Bakagalas (バカガラス) aircraft schematic/size comparison

Tags: nausicaa-of-the-valley-of-the-wind

In the anime and manga *Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind*, several large aircraft appear. I believe they are called 'バカガラス' (possible transliteration: *Bakagalas*). I plan to make 3D models of them, as it seems it hasn't been done.

Are there any schematic or good size comparisons for these?

Comment: N.T. Izumi has [a Flickr album](https://www.flickr.com/photos/ntizumi/albums/72157690708090432) of Bakagalas model and its schematic. These images are copyrighted and I haven't asked the permission to reproduced on here, so I just put a link on here first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is apparently inspired by the German Aircraft Me323D-1.
There are some schematics for a model of that here https://www.1999.co.jp/10548533

Google image search of  "バカガラス　模型"　brings up Japanese plastic models/drawings, if that helps.

The Japanese Wikipedia says there isn't any official documentation on the specific size of the plane, but a fan site (http://www.ghibli-freak.net/nausicaa/mecha.html) says it has an overall length of over 100 meters.

On a side note, someone made a real-life Nausicaa glider, which is awesome.
https://www.makery.info/en/2016/11/08/il-a-realise-le-planeur-de-nausicaa/

Answer (score 0):

The Flickr account belongs to me.  I am more than willing to share any information, but note that the sketches are just my own guesstimations.  If you compare them to screen shots, the proportions (especially the wingspan) seem to vary considerably.  I do not think the artists doing Nausicaa really sat down and figured out the exact size of the thing.  I just took elements and proportions I liked and combined them.

That being said, one way to start estimating the size is comparing the Nausicaa Gunship when it is being loaded into the cargo hold.  By using the Nitto/Bandai 1/72 Gunship, the minimum hold dimensions can be established (accounting for its width and height with folded wings).  My sketches were ostensibly 1/200, but after doing this exercise, I figure they are closer to 1/250.